# Where is the editing profile feature?

Tags: support

Under my account I remember I could edit my profile under "settings". But now I don't find the feature there. Has it been moved somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: You have to access your profile from the main site; not from your meta profile. You should see a tab up top that says "Edit Profile and Settings."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Meta profile has a [settings page](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) but it does not allow you to edit your profile (about me etc.), because it's automatically synchronized from the main site. As @n8te says, use the main site for this, e.g. by going to https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current.

[image]

That's the main site; the 'Edit profile' link is missing on meta:

[image]